# mvn android:deploy -> Unfortunately App has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I did a basic Android project. I run it in eclipse with the AVD and all fine. The app it runs. But when I try: `mvn android:deploy` all seems fine, but the AVD says: `Unfortunately App has stopped`

**mvn clean install**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SakebuApp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\generated-sources\r, -M, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\assets, -I, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ SakebuApp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ SakebuApp ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:proguard (default-proguard) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ SakebuApp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:emma (default-emma) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:dex (default-dex) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar, --dex, --output=C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\classes.dex, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\classes]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:apk (default-apk) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] Copying local assets files to combined assets directory.
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package, -f, -M, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets, -I, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar, -F, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.ap_]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:internal-pre-integration-test (default-internal-pre-integration-test) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:internal-integration-test (default-internal-integration-test) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.1.2:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.apk to C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sakebu\android\SakebuApp\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\SakebuApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apk
[INFO] Installing C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\pom.xml to C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sakebu\android\SakebuApp\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\SakebuApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.jar to C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sakebu\android\SakebuApp\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\SakebuApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp-sources.jar to C:\Users\HP\.m2\repository\com\sakebu\android\SakebuApp\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\SakebuApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.910s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 15 02:39:34 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**mvn android:deploy**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SakebuApp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:deploy (default-cli) @ SakebuApp ---
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [dump, xmltree, C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.apk, AndroidManifest.xml]
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=2)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0" (Raw: "1.0")
    A: package="com.sakebu.android" (Raw: "com.sakebu.android")
    E: uses-sdk (line=7)
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0xf
    E: application (line=9)
      A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f040001
      A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f020000
      E: activity (line=12)
        A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f040001
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".SakebuAppActivity" (Raw: ".SakebuAppActivity")
        E: intent-filter (line=15)
          E: action (line=16)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
          E: category (line=18)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
[INFO] Waiting for initial device list from the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter not set, using all attached devices
[INFO] Successfully uninstalled com.sakebu.android from emulator-5554_sakebuEM_unknown_sdk
[INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter not set, using all attached devices
[INFO] Successfully installed C:\Workspace\SakebuApp\target\SakebuApp.apk to emulator-5554_sakebuEM_unknown_sdk
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.919s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 15 02:42:38 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sakebu.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>SakebuApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>SakebuApp</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>15</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>sakebuEM</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Output when I click on the icon app:**
`Unfortunately App has stopped`

**Output Dalvik when I run mvn android:deploy**

```
06-15 08:53:39.025: D/AndroidRuntime(2173): Shutting down VM
06-15 08:53:39.025: W/dalvikvm(2173): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sakebu.android/com.sakebu.android.SakebuAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sakebu.android.SakebuAppActivity
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sakebu.android.SakebuAppActivity
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-15 08:53:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(2173):     ... 11 more
06-15 08:53:39.265: I/dalvikvm(2173): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-15 08:53:39.285: I/dalvikvm(2173): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-15 08:53:39.705: I/dalvikvm(2173): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-15 08:53:39.775: I/dalvikvm(2173): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Build went well, so if you want to know why the app stops, you'll have to look at the logcat output. Find the stacktrace, the exceptions, they will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I post the output Dalvik. It gives me a ClassNotFoundExpection in the project main activity. But then I don't understand why in a case if I run the ADV directly in eclipse, yes it run whitout any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new maven android project. I think the problem was an incorrect archetype. I have followed this steps in the new project: [m2Eclipse Integration](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/wiki/GettingStarted) but you have to update android-maven-plugin to version 3.2.0 otherwise not working.